# Is it normal at beginner level to feel piano pieces uninteresting?

Tags: piano, chords, digital-piano, beethoven

This is the most stupid question that you may hear in your life but I dont have anybody to help me here.

I always loved the sound of piano from my childhood but never took it seriously. In last few months I was listening to different piano pieces of Yiruma and Einaudi. I loved the sound so much that I decided to learn piano.

As my financial condition is extremely poor I may need to utilize my half a year savings to buy a basic digital piano. So I thought before I invest I should listen more and more piano in youtube to ensure that it does not happen that after couple of months I don't find it interesting and leave it entirely causing my precious money to go in vain.

So I started.  When I was listening to different composers in youtube, except 5 or 6 pieces  none of them is touching me. Pieces of Chopin, Beethoven felt like complete noise , other less complex works also did not felt good in ears. And now I am heavily confused whether to proceed or not.

My Questions:

1. Is it a normal phenomena for every beginners?
2. Can it happen that, as I dont know anything about piano, I am not able to understand the notes which is why I felt them uninteresting?
3. Can I generate my interest when I start learning it and learn more and more?

I believe I am overthinking (which I am expert in) due to my financial constraints. Kindly help me to take a decision...

Comment: There is almost no other instrument that has such a wide range of possible styles as the piano. If you like hearing even a single way of playing it, then it's already worth engaging with it.

Comment: If you are going to learn any instrument, piano is definitely the best to start with.  Everything you learn on a piano can be transferred to almost any other instrument.  As for interesting, first learn to play them properly, then figure out *why* you still think they are uninteresting, and then try "improving" them yourself.  I remember showing someone "do ti la … re do" (boring), then playing the same notes with a different timing "Joy to the world …".

Answer (score 2):

It can be sometimes that music which is unfamiliar to us in style doesn't sound like "music". What "sounds like music" to people is often that which is familiar to them, and often in a style that they heard a lot when quite young.

(When I was young I became a jazz fan by listening to older style artists like Louis Armstrong and Count Basie - but the first time I bought a Charlie Parker record it came as quite a shock. Now I love his records.)

I would say keep listening - come back to those pieces every now and again. Over time your ears are likely to develop, especially if you are learning and playing.

Keep studying piano. Music takes a lot and time and effort to learn but is one of the most rewarding things you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Yiruma is the 'River flows in you' guy?   Sure, you can have lots of fun playing in that style.  But, as you've discovered, that's just one small area of what a piano can do.   If the dramatics of Beethoven or Chopin don't attract you, how about Debussy?

Or the elegant simplicity of Mozart?

Or some boogie-woogie?

Or 'cool' jazz?